# Changing height of element moves element outside of viewport when page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll, viewport

We got a list of cards that show a small part of a textbox. That textbox is limited in height via CSS. When a user clicks on "Details" the textboxes height is changed via javascript to the real height of the content.
The problem is, that when the viewport / window is scrolled and the cards height increases, it pushes itself out of the viewport. When the window is not scrolled at all, it works.

Please see the following video: https://monosnap.com/file/HauaJrJlkx2MBLGt3QOa5ulJMxFTnv

0:00 -> 0:08 is the desired opening / closing behavior that I want

0:09 -> 0:16 is the behavior I do not want, as the top text is moved out of the viewport.

Is there a way to keep the viewport, preferably without JS?

Edit: This happens only in Chrome (84.0.41), in Firefox and Safari it works as expected.

I can send you a link to the staging environment if necessary, please contact me via info@felixhagspiel.de

Comment: Hi Felix, you really need to post a [reprex] for ppl to help you out, you know the drill....

Comment: @RenevanderLende Yes I know, unfortunately we have to check if we are allowed to post the link to the staging env first (or if we can DM it). I will send you the link as soon as we get an answer. Also, I just noticed that this is a chrome only problem.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I can PM you the link to the staging environment. If you do not want to post your email here please send a mail to info@felixhagspiel.de and I will answer with the details if that is okay for you. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks it's done more logical that you want to be. As control placed in a bottom element (bad UI) better keep this control in viewport (strange that chest Crome thinks so).

So just `display:flex` build all this magic :)

Please look examples
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1faTDwJBQEv-V96O8-HC-8R2_hXkGzsQJ/view?usp=sharing

UPDATE: also please remove

```
tabindex="0"
```

And use `button` instead `div` to get the same logic with the keyboard navigation.

On Video last Chrome
Google Chrome is up to date
Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)